# Daylight To Standard Timezone

Tags: java, web-services, api, timezone

I have web application in which I have to draw a chart according to time.
Now because the Daylight time is changing to standard time on 3rd November at 2AM.

I have change the code according to these time changes, but I want to know some API which tell me this date and time when these changes occur. Like "3rd November at 2AM".

Answer (score 1):

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a great solution. Check [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#nextTransition%28long%29).